# How can I skip one or multiple examples under Scenario Outline Examples for Specflow

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cucumber, specflow, scenarios

I have scenario outline example and i want to skip for one or more example

```
Scenario Outline : 
 Given user is using <app>
 Then user is logged in 
 Examples: 
          |app  |
          |test |
          |local|
```

How can i skip the run for 'test' here ?

Using specflow - 3.* with nunit as runner

Thanks for your help!!

In  Step Def File

```
If(app=="test")
  //skip the run for this condition
else
  run for others
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a `#` at the beginning of the example line that you want to skip, e.g.

```
#           |test |
```

If you're using Visual Studio then you can skip multiple examples by highlighting them and then holding down the `Ctrl` key and pressing `K` and then `C` (same as commenting out lines of code in any other language).

Comment: This is not what i am looking for .. i want my run for that condition should be skipped

Comment: Are you saying you want to skip just one of the steps in your test for a given value of `app`, rather than skipping the whole test?

Comment: Yes you got me right. I want to Skip rows based on the condition for the given value of app

Comment: So you just surround the body of the test step method with `if (app != "test")` so that it doesn't do anything for the example where the app parameter is "test"?

Comment: How the test will show it's skipped with the message in the report ? I need the report should say the test is skipped for that value as value is not active

Comment: If you mean you want it to show as a yellow icon in the VS test explorer then that can't be done as the explorer shows status at a test case / example level, not a test step level. If you want to show in standard output that the test step was skipped, use something like `Console.WriteLine($"Test step {nameof(MyStep)} skipped");` in the else branch.

Comment: I tried using _scenarioContainer.pending() and it works as i have configured it to Ignore in specflow,json and i get the yellow mark in test explorer however i get the message saying some of the steps are pending i dont want to show that message in test explorer how can i change or suppress that message

Comment: I'm not sure what `_scenarioContainer` is, I'm guessing it's a private field instantiated somewhere in your test class? I found `ScenarioContext.StepIsPending();` which not only writes to standard output that the test step is pending, but also shows the whole test case in VS test explorer as "not run" (exclamation mark on a blue background), which isn't quite the same as what you're seeing, because clearly I'm doing something a bit different to what you're doing.

Comment: My suggestion would be for you to reflect on this discussion in the comments under an answer which resulted from me not understanding your question correctly, and then edit your original question so that it includes the information you've provided in response to my questions about what it is you want to achieve. Ideally you could also include some code showing exactly what you've already tried and explaining why its results are not satisfactory - please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example if you haven't already seen it.